# How to retry job until fail in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I have a number of jobs on my queue table. I want to run a job until fail. After that job, the queue polls next job.

Currently Laravel Queue pulls all jobs to run row by row. But I don't want to pull next job unless first job is succeed.

Comment: php artisan queue:retry 5 and look 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

Comment: I don't talk about failed jobs. These jobs which are on processing. @MustafaToker

Answer (score 1):

If you can detect if your first job is done or not, you can use:

```
$this->release(10);
```

inside the job to release the job 10 seconds if the first is not finished.

This way allows you to process a job if you want or not and return to the queue if it's necessary.